# Need Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

I am working on deploying a SharePoint web part. I am working on the server via remote desktop connection, and needed to compile a .dll file using Visual Studio Command Prompt. I discovered that the server only has Visual Studio 2010 Shell, and that lacks VS Tools including Command Prompt. I tried researching this issue and all of them dealt with older VS that had to add it via Tools menu, which is ineffective since Shell has only the application and nothing else.

What I need to do specifically on VS Command Prompt is add a webextension.dll to Assembly.

**How do I add VS Command Prompt to a VS Shell? Could I use regular command prompt as a workaround?**

Comment: The Visual Studio command prompt simply sets some environmental variables so that the VS tools and SDK/.Net command-line tools can work properly. If you don't have the VS tools and other things installed, the VS command prompt would do nothing for you. (You can see this on a machine that *does* have VS installed; simply right-click the Start menu option to open the VS command prompt and look at the properties; it launches a .bat file. Open the .bat file and look at the contents to see what it does.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the Visual Studio 2010 tools?

then add to the Assemblies:
References>Assemblies>Framework>System.Web.Extensions

HTH

Comment: Is this a directory path or a menu in VS?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, under References.

Comment: The only other item that I can think of, that may help, is:http://vscmdshell.codeplex.com/